# Cropping image with imagemagick linux script not working

Tags: linux, command, imagemagick, crop

This is my first post here because I am getting desperate.
I need to write a script that will resize images and then chop X amount of pixels from the edges depending on what the user input is.

I got the resize working just fine, but I am having major issues with the chop/crop.

I removed all variables to see if I could find what was wrong but I couldn't and I have been trying for 2 hours getting it to work but I just simply can't

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 percentage=50%
  4 
  5 for i in *.jpg; do
  6         printf "Resize $i\n"
  7         convert "$i" -resize $percentage "output_$i"
  8 done
 14 
 15 for j in *.jpg; do
 16         printf "Crop $j\n"
 17         convert $j -gravity North -chop  0x10 tempimagechop.png 
 18         convert tempimagechop.png -gravity South -chop 0x10 tempimagechop.png
 19         convert tempimagechop.png -gravity East -chop 0x10 tempimagechop.png
 20         convert tempimagechop.png -gravity West -chop  0x10 "Chop_$j"
 21         
 22 done
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, chop and crop are totally different. -chop will remove part of an image, leaving the rest. -crop will crop out and save part of an image. You are doing a chop not a crop. To do a crop use -crop WxH+X+Y +repage. Where +X+Y are the upper left corner of the WxH section you want to keep, namely, the offsets to the top left of the area you want. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_repage and
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_gravity

Your chop commands are wrong. To chop at the top (north) use -chop 0x**10**. To chop at the left (west) use -chop **10**x0. To chop at the right (east) use -chop **10**x0. To chop at the bottom (south) use -chop 0x**10**. The first number is columns to chop and the second number is rows to chop. You also do not need to use separate converts. You can string them one after the other into one convert. You should also add +repage afterwards. See the -chop link above.

But you might be better using one -crop as described above by specifying the WxH and the top left corner at +X+Y